# mhddfs not support file split.. if file size exceed limit of single storage device

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, virtual, fuse

I'm using mhddfs to combine multiple drives that are mounted over network using NFS.

e.g.
There are three machines

```
Server Name  Dir    Space
Server 1     /home  10 GB Space
Server 2     /home  10 GB Space
Server 3     /home  10 GB Space
```

Using NFS i mounted the following:

```
Server 1 /home to Server 3 /home/mount1
Server 2 /home to Server 3 /home/mount3
```

Then using mhddfs i merge or unified mount1 and mount 2 e.g.

```
mhddfs /home/server/mount1,/home/server/mount2 /home/server/mount
```

Now i have 30 GB space altogether. but when i tried to write the file in mount directory that has more than 10 GB space it fails...

It seems mhddfs can't split large file e.g. 20 GB file.. so that it can store

Please give an idea, that how i can achive this ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inherent limitation of mhddfs. It works by simply combining the contents of the underlying devices into a single directory, and stores new files into whichever drive has sufficient free space. Since there is no drive in your system that can actually store a 20 GB file, the resulting merged filesystem cannot store one either.

Comment: Is there any other solution rather than mhddfs ??

Comment: None that I can recommend without knowing a lot more about your situation.

Comment: I have situation in which i have to make a data server to setup Wikipideia dumps for research purpose. I've to make Teraytes of space available. I have several Hard drives and systems in my university that has maximum capacity of 500 GB indiviually. I want to setup there network and configure NFS and mhddfs(Or any other fusion) to make single data directory in which i can write terabytes  of data.. Hope it is clear.. let me know if need further details.. Thanks

Comment: Talk to your university system administrators. They will know what your options are better than I do, and may have some suggestions.

Comment: unfortuantely my network Admin advised me to purchase the comodity server machines that worth of thousand dollars... So that's why i asked the things here to setup some cost efffective solution...

Comment: can we achive this through AUFS or unifos ??